# Google Classroom Rest API Patching 'text' in announcement does not work

Tags: rest, google-classroom

When we try to patch 'text' in a Google Classroom announcement using REST API we get an error. If we remove 'text' from the updateMask, it works. Others have also reported this, but there is no answer. Here are the details:

```
Request URL: https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses/xxxxxxx2746/announcements/xxxxxxx8639?updateMask=text,state
Request Method: PATCH

Payload:
{text: "Live Session at 1/31/2019", state: "PUBLISHED"}

Response:
Status Code: 400 
Remote Address: 172.217.15.106:443
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "updateMask: Non-supported update mask fields specified",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
            "field": "updateMask",
            "description": "Non-supported update mask fields specified"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is a bug in the Classroom API right now. The best workaround right now is to delete and re-create the post with the [announcements.delete](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.announcements/delete) and [announcements.create](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.announcements/create) endpoints. You can keep track of the progress of the bug [here](http://issuetracker.google.com/123653027).